# Html to fire an event

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help with this please?
I have a webpage with an asp.net frame on it- the frame shows the contents of an html document. 
When someone clicks on a link in the html document, I need to show some content in another frame *on the same page*.

So, the question is, what should 'myTag' be in the following...

e.g.
//this is the contents of my html file`

```
<p>to be or not to be, <myTag>that</myTag>  is the question</p>
```

Whatever 'myTag' is (maybe a piece of javascript? don't know), it should be able to fire an event on the server so I can send some more text to the other frame on the page

Any ideas?

thanks..

Comment: fire an event on the server?  events are javascript/DOM-related, if you want to call something on the server and reload the page that is a different question I think.

Comment: agreed. this question would be less ambiguous with a different title.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is give the other frame an ID or some way to easily get to it with javascript.  Then inside your iframe, you could do something like:

```
var other_frame_document = window.parent.document.getElementById('other_frame').contentWindow.document;
// example 1: set the HTML of the other frame from a string.
// this is usually a bad idea because of XSS.
other_frame_document.body.innerHTML = '<b>aloha</b>';

// example 2: better way is to manipulate the DOM in the other iframe
var elm = other_frame_document.createElement('b');
elm.appendChild(other_frame_document.createTextNode('aloha'));
other_frame_document.body.appendChild(elm);
```

Comment: this is a good solution combined with using "onclick" attribute as suggested below -- in your onclick function, you could then set innerHTML of the iframe with a given id.

Comment: thanks guys- it's given me a few pointers- I'm reposting the question in a slightly better way..

Answer (score 0):

that is one way to fire an action.

Or you can bind the action using jQuery (or some other library) when the DOM loads, like this:

```
jQuery("#myTagId").bind("click", function() { ... });
```

This will cause the event to fire when the element is clicked.

You can then use ajax to call the server to update the other frame.

Comment: try this combined with the solution Yobert posted.